# Drag and drop ondragleave executing before mouse leaves

Tags: javascript, typescript, drag-and-drop

I have draggable div's that act as a tab bar where you can drag and re-organize the tabs. Moving the tabs and dragging them around works fine, but I am having issues with `ondragenter` and `ondragleave`. What I want to do is change the background color of the tab when you drag over it, and when the drag leaves, I want the background to go back to what it was.

The issue that is occurring, is that when you enter the tab, the class is added and it changes color but then once you move the mouse over a sub-element the class gets removed and the color is gone.

What is causing this? https://jsfiddle.net/cypqgrrm/

```
class Tab {

    public createTab(){
        let tab = document.createElement('div');
        tab.classList.add('tab');
        tab.draggable = true;
        tab.ondragenter = this.onTabDragEnter.bind(this);
        tab.ondragleave = this.onTabDragLeave.bind(this);
    }

    private onTabDragEnter(e: DragEvent) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        let target = <HTMLElement>e.currentTarget;
        target.classList.add('drag-hover');
    }

    private onTabDragLeave(e: DragEvent) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        let target = <HTMLElement>e.currentTarget;
        target.classList.remove('drag-hover');
    }

}
```

Here is the css:

```
.tab.drag-hover {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable pointer events for the children of the drag target to avoid the `dragleave` event caused by entering children:

```
.tab.drag-hover * {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: But I need drag leave to run when the target is actually left